# Maximum likelihood function (MLE) for Levy distribution

Tags: statistics, estimation

I am a student who is writing a little thesis belonged in the applied mathematics category.

I choose a "Levy distribution" 
defined as, 
\begin{equation}
 \lambda(t;u,c) = \begin{cases}
 \sqrt{\frac{c}{2\pi}}\frac{ e^{-\frac{c} {2(t-u)} }}  {(t-u)^{3/2}} & \text{if  } t>u \\
 0 & \text{otherwise}
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}
to examine the behavior of the variables.

Now I thought I had to apply the MLE to obtain the good estimation of the parameter: $c,u $

However, after calculating the derivative of logarithm of the levy distribution. I obtained only 
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\lambda(t;u,c)} {dc} = \frac{c-t+u} {2ct-2cu} = 0 \iff c = t-u
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\lambda(t;u,c)} {du} = -\frac{c-3t+3u} {2(t-u)^{2}} = 0 \iff u = t-\frac{c}{3}
\end{equation}

However, both the parameters $c$ and $u$ are dependent on each other. Could somebody suggest me the better method for estimating?

Thank you very much.

Comment: PDF defn:  "if x > u" should presumably be:  "if t > u"

Comment: Oops my bad, I corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter $u$ in your Levy pdf is just a shift parameter that adjusts the lower bound from 0. It is equivalent to the transformation $X = T + u$, where random variable $T$ has pdf $f(t)$:

[image]

The following plot illustrates the pdf, as parameter $c$ changes:

[image]

From the plot, the lower bound parameter will generally be clearly defined by the data itself (unless parameter $c$ is very large)  ... So, the way I would proceed would be to:

a) zero-shift your data so that the lower bound is 0;  *i.e.* newdata = data - min[data]

b) then your problem reduces to finding the MLE of parameter $c$, for the single parameter model.

That can be solved by hand (if you prefer), or get a computer to do the work for you. Here I am using the `mathStatica` add-on to *Mathematica* (I am one of the authors of the former). `mathStatica` has a special `SuperLog` function specially designed for formulating log-likelihood problems:

[image]

Then, for a random sample of size $n$ drawn on $T$, the log-likelihood function is:

[image]

The score function is the gradient of the log-likelihood with respect to $c$:

[image]

Setting the score to zero and solving for $c$ corresponds to the first-order conditions:

[image]

Finally, check the second-order condition, evaluated at `solc`:

[image]

... reveals that the Hessian is strictly negative at the FOC.

Therefore, the MLE of $c$ is:

$$\hat{c}=\frac{n}{\underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\sum }}\frac{1}{T_i}.}$$

Answer (score 2):

Your post present a computation when the sample $\{t\}$ has size $1$. Then $\partial_c\log\lambda$ has the sign of $(t-u)-c$ and $\partial_u\log\lambda$ has the sign of $c-3(t-u)$ (watch out for the signs in the post...). The domain of $(c,t)$ is $c\gt0$ and $0\leqslant u\lt t$.

Let $\ell(c,v)=\lambda(t;c,t-v)$. Then, for every $(c,v)$, 
$$
\ell(c,v)\leqslant\ell(v,v)\leqslant\ell(v,\tfrac13v)\leqslant\ell(\tfrac13v,\tfrac13v)\leqslant\ell(\tfrac13v,\tfrac19v)\leqslant\ldots
$$
This shows that the supremum of $\ell$ is reached when $(c,v)\to(0,0)$, hence the supremum of $\lambda(t;c,u)$ for some given $t$ is reached when $(c,u)\to(0,t)$. To check this, note that
$$
2\log\lambda(t;c,u)=\log c-\frac{c}{t-u}-3\log(t-u),
$$
hence
$\lambda(t;\varepsilon,t-\varepsilon)=-1-2\log\varepsilon\to+\infty$ when $\varepsilon\to0$. To sum up, using the MLE approach for a sample of size $1$ seems to be a bad idea. Some remarks are in order here.

- First, this degenerate behaviour probably disappears when the sample $\{t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_n\}$ has size $n\geqslant4$ (computations omitted).
- Second, if $u$ is known, optimizing $\lambda(t;c,u)$ over $c$ yields $\hat c=t-u$ when the sample has size $1$ and, for an i.i.d. sample of size $n$,
  $$
  \frac{n}{\hat c}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{t_k-u}.
  $$
- Third, if $c$ is known, optimizing $\lambda(t;c,u)$ over $u$ yields $\hat u=t-\frac13c$ when the sample has size $1$ and, for an i.i.d. sample of size $n$, $\hat u$ should solve
  $$
  c\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{(t_k-\hat u)^2}=3\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{t_k-\hat u}.
  $$